# Does Git flow deletes branch on remote server?

Tags: git, git-flow

I am using git along with **git flow**. Here git flow has a `develop` branch. Whenever i need to start feature i type

```
git flow feature start new
```

a new branch `feature/new` is created. Then i do the changes and **commit** them using

```
git push origin feature/new
```

After comitting the changes I finish feature using

```
git flow feature finish new
```

it **deletes** `feature/new` branch locally. Now I am **switched to develop branch by git flow** and I again type

```
git push origin develop
```

which make changes to remote server `develop` branch

If I type `git branch -a`, the  new branch got deleted from the local but it is there on the server with name `remotes/origin/feature/new`

**Does git flow delete branches on remote server** which are deleted at my local machine?

Please tell me if I am making some mistake.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/blob/15aab26490facf285acef56cb5d61025eacb3a69/git-flow-feature#L352) it seems that the remote feature branch is deleted only if you call `git flow feature finish` with `-F`.

However, this fetches the remote before finishing the feature. From the [docs](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments):

> **-F** fetch from $ORIGIN before performing finish

Otherwise you can [delete the remote branch](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Deleting-Remote-Branches) manually with:

```
git push origin :feature/new
```

Comment: Also note that if you never pushed that branch upstream to a remote server like 'git push --set-upstream origin branch', when calling 'git flow feature finish' you will never have the remote branch.

Answer (score 30):

May I suggest using the git-flow AVH Edition.

Like Stefan said, the original version only deletes the remote branch when you use `-F`, which is kinda strange. The AVH Edition fixes this quirky behavior, it will always delete the local and remote feature branch on a finish, unless you specify either

- `--keep`, which keeps the local and remote.
- `--keeplocal`, which keeps the local, but deletes the remote.
- `--keepremote`, which keeps the remote, but deletes the local.

You can find git-flow AVH Edition on [github](http://goo.gl/9hGZ3).

Comment: Does AVH Edition handle ```feature pull``` better too? I just set a bounty, because the ```feature pull``` in original git-flow is very confusing (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412750/why-doesnt-git-flow-feature-pull-track), appreciate any input to have a cannonical answer.

Comment: The feature pull command will be deprecated per version 2.0 and only feature track will be available.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically tag where the feature branches HEAD was before it removes it? I like to see the little green tags in git-web, but when the remote is deleted, those go away.

Comment: Note: git-flow AVH edition is the default in Git for Windows. You can confirm this by running `git flow version`.

Comment: Also, you can change the default behavior with, for example, `git config gitflow.feature.finish.keepremote true`.

Answer (score 7):

What I had to do:

```
git flow feature delete -f name_feature
```

The -f is necessary if there are changes inside the feature branch.

```
git push origin --delete feature/name_feature
```

That is to delete the remote branch as well.